# Is the new companion from the 80's-90's?

Tags: doctor-who

In [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaLficIRInM) released by the BBC, the new *Doctor Who* companion, Bill, is introduced.

From her outfit

- shirt from the sleeve art for Prince's Purple Rain, released 1984
- denim jacket, popular in the 80's
- her high-top sneakers

To this *Back to the Future* (1985) reference, in which the Doctor implies 2017 is in the future, relative to Bill's timeline:

> DOCTOR: We need to get back.
>
> BILL: Back where?
>
> DOCTOR: To the **future. *2017* needs us!**

It would seem Bill is from the late 80's or early 90's. Is this the case?

Comment: Since [series 10 will be aired in 2017](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2016-02-08/doctor-who-series-10-to-start-filming-in-may---but-new-companion-is-yet-to-audition), the implication is that the Doctor and Bill are in the past during that clip, not that Bill is from the past.

Comment: There’s this thing about fashion — it tends to come back around.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Everything old can be made new again ... like democracy."

Answer (score 1):

### No; she's from the present.

From S10E4, "Knock Knock":

> HARRY: Tenancy agreement. Same as ours. Six signatures. Jake Christie, Annie Wren, Jonathan Frost.
>   DOCTOR: What's the date?
>   HARRY: Er, **1997**. Sarah Tiller, Mark Hopethorne, Carl Richards.
>   [...]
>   HARRY: Doctor.
>   (There are more sets of boxes. Harry picks up a David Bowie single - Heroes by the look of the photo on the sleeve - and another tenancy agreement.)
>   HARRY: **1977**.
>   DOCTOR: **1957. Every twenty years.**
>
> <sub>-- [transcript](http://chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/36-4.html) (emphasis mine)</sub>

That implies that the default setting of Series 10 - the 'present day', from Bill's point of view - is **2017**.